# Inline Edit Buttons not Showing for One Org Only

Tags: visualforce, inlineeditsupport

I have a Visualforce page which uses inline editing with Save and Cancel buttons only appearing when you are in edit mode.  The portion of the page that performs this function is here:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="listPanel">
<apex:pageBlock title="{!$Label.Loads}">

    <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
        <apex:commandButton id="saveButton"   value="{!$Label.Save}"   action="{!doSave}"   style="display:none;" rerender="listPanel"/>
        <apex:commandButton id="cancelButton" value="{!$Label.Cancel}" action="{!doCancel}" style="display:none;" rerender="listPanel" immediate="true"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>

    <apex:pageBlocktable value="{!allLoadsList}" var="l">

        <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton,cancelButton"/>
```

As you can see the Save and Cancel button display when you go into edit mode.  This works fine for hundreds of our customer orgs:

[image]

The buttons do not appear in one and only one org....  Why would the buttons not appear in one org out of 100??  Thanks for your help!

Comment: What happens in that one org? Are they able to edit (just no buttons)? Is it across all users (admin, etc)?

Comment: Hi, Kris -- Yes they can go into edit mode but the buttons don't show.  Same issue for all users, all browsers.  Really strange.

Comment: what have you debugged? I'd guess looking at their `Setup --> Session Settings` selections would be a good starting point as it seems something is different in that one org. In particular, the clickjack protections being enabled for VF pages.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, Kris.  I just checked -- No difference between the session settings of the problem org and those orgs not experiencing the issue.

Comment: Have you verified that the buttons are actually missing from the DOM itself and not hidden by CSS? I see `style="display:none;"` on both `commandButton` elements so I'm just covering bases.

Comment: No, the buttons are not missing from the DOM.  The usual behavior on the inline edit tag is to display the hidden buttons on edit but they are not for one and only one org.